# compare lines and make new line out of matches

Tags: string, file, powershell, compare, match

I have two files:

file1:

```
Server A sent Mail with testuser1@testdom.com
Server A sent Mail with testuser2@testdom.com
Server B sent Mail with testuser3@testdom.com
```

file2:

```
testuser1@testdom.com
testuser2@testdom.com
testuser3@testdom.com
```

For example if the email address "testuser1@testdom.com" from file2 is also in file1, it should append this line from file1 to the new file file3.
Is it possible two have many files and compare them with file2 in one step?

This is what I tried, but it doesn't exactly do what I want:

```
compare (cat $file1) (cat $file2) | Out-File $file3
```

and this: (prints only the lines which are exactly the same, but I need it partially)

```
Get-Content $file1 | ForEach-Object {
    $file1_Line = $_
    Get-Content $file2 | Where-Object {$_.Contains($file1_Line)} |
        Out-File -FilePath $file3 -Append
}
```

Comment: "it should create a new file with that email addresses or lines that are in file1" - could you clarify this?

Comment: For example if the email address "testuser1@testdom.com" from file2 is also in file1, it should append this line from file1 to file3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
$cInFile1 = "infile1.txt"
$cInFile2 = "infile2.txt"
$cOutFile = "outfile.txt"

# Reading files as collections on lines.
$cLines1 = Get-Content -Path $cInFile1
$cLines2 = Get-Content -Path $cInFile2

foreach ($sLine in $cLines1) {
    $sAddress = ($sLine -split ' ')[-1]
    if ($sAddress -in $cLines2) {
        $sLine | Out-File -FilePath $cOutFile -Append
    }
}
```